# Convert List to Maybe<Map>

Tags: java-8, java-stream, rx-java

I want to convert List< Long> to Maybe>. Here is example.

```
class Structure
{
   Long id;
   Long data;
}

class makeStructure{
    Maybe<Structure> getStructure(Long id)
    {
       return someMaybe;
    }
}
```

if the origin data is like below.  
1. Structure{ id : 100, data :200} 
2. Structure{ id : 101, data :201}

I want to convert it to Maybe< Map< Long, Structure>> containing below two data. 
(Structure id used as key)

1. (100, Structure{ id : 100, data :200})
2. (101, Structure{ id : 101, data :201})

I tried something like below.

```
List<Long> list;//somethig in it
makeStructure makeStructrue = new makeStructure();
Map<Long, Structure> result = list.stream()
  .map(i->makeStructrue.getStructure(i))
  .map(v->v.blockingGet())
  .collect(Collector.toMap(k->k.getId(),k->k);
return Maybe.just(result);
```

But this is not the result that i want in two reason.
First, I used blockGet method
Second, the result of collect is Map not Maybe. I wonder just using Maybe.just(result) ensure the same result.

to get a good performance ***I tried not to use blockingGet();***

Is there any good idea to make clean code?

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. And update the question, never add more infos via comments. For me, what is definitely missing: how do create Structure objects?  Or is `getStructure` assumed to be static?!

Comment: `blockingGet()` used for Maybe<Structure> to get Structure hope you understand.